# Lamnda Python 3.8 GPG decryption can not find gpg binary

Tags: python-3.x, gnupg, python-gnupgp

I'm trying to use a lambda function to decrypt files coming to S3, I download the files without issues, but when I try to decrypt them the gpg can not be found. I;ve tried using both `python-gnupg` and `gnupg` but both failed mentioning that gnupg is not available on the OS. Below my code for isntantiating GPG  in python
It works well with python 3.7, but if I upgrade to 3.8, Lambda uses AMazon Linux 2, which doesn't come with gpg. How can I make it work with python 3.8 in Lambda?

`gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/tmp')`

Error:

```
OSError: Unable to run gpg (gnupg) - it may not be available
```

All the examples I've found don't seem to  do anything extra. I'm packaging the python-gnugp package and all other python packages for my function

is the gpg binary available in Lambda? how can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bundle the gpg binary and its dependencies and deliver them in your package. In my package i bundle them into a folder named 'gpg', then when I use gpg in my Lambda function, I do this:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    old = os.environ.get("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
    if old:
        os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "./gpg" + ":" + old
    else:
        os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "./gpg"
    
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/tmp', gpgbinary='./gpg/gpg2', verbose=False)
```

Comment: I ended up packaging the gog binaries with the Lambda, can you add an explanation on how to get the binaries?


To get the binaries I launched an EC2 instance and got them form:

    1.    gpg file from   '/usr/bin/gpg'
    2.    lib files from  '/usr/lib64/'

Comment: Would it possible to share the binaries and its dependencies? I also have a similar usecase

Comment: Finally manage to bundle the executable to make it work for Python 3.10. The file I had to bundle includes: gpg, libassuan.so.0, libgcrypt.so.11 and libgpg-error.so.0. These files could easily found on any linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that 3.7 lambda python environment includes the GPG, while the later versions don't. I think it's better to use a Python implementation of the PGP protocol rather than relying on GPG that you would have to bundle with the lambda (and bundling it is a pain).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46665862/1328513) for example (it suggests using pgpy library)