# Calling GPG method from AWS serverless

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3, gnupg, python-gnupgp

I deploy my serverless function using [zip method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html).

I'm trying to encrypt the file using the following code:

```
import boto3
import gnupg

def lambda_handler(event, context):
        s3=boto3.resource('s3')

        s3.meta.client.download_file('my_bucket','plain.txt','/tmp/plain.txt')
        s3.meta.client.download_file('my_bucket','public.key','/tmp/public.key')
        
        key_data = open('/tmp/public.key').read()

        gpg = gnupg.GPG('/tmp')
        priv_key = gpg.import_keys(key_data)
        
        with open('/tmp/plain.txt','rb') as a_file:
          gpg.encrypt_file(a_file,key_data,output='plain.txt.gpg')
     
        return 'ok'
```

but I got the following error:

```
  "errorMessage": "Unable to run gpg (/tmp) - it may not be available."
```

what's the correct way to run gpg from serverless?

Comment: How exactly are you importing the library using .zip file? What exactly is the error? What's the resulting folder structure?

Comment: I updated the question following your comment @gshpychka

Comment: See the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66770313/lamnda-python-3-8-gpg-decryption-can-not-find-gpg-binary?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: How did you package the dependencies in the zip file? What is the resulting folder structure?

Comment: It also looks like the gpg binary used to be a part of Python 3.7, but it's not starting from Python 3.8

Answer (score 1):

The Lambda runtime doesn't contain arbitrary executables like GPG.

Your best option is probably to use a native Python package, so that ideally you don't need an external binary, or a wrapper package such as [python-gnupg](https://pypi.org/project/python-gnupg/).

You may need to package needed binaries with your Lambda deployment package or as part of an underlying Lambda layer.